# Log GWT method name in the access log

Tags: gwt, logging

In GWT, requests are sent to XXXX.rpc which maps to a "GWT Controller" (RemoteService).  The method name that will be invoked is buried in the post of this request.

Is there a way to send the method name as an additional HTTP header or as part of the URL?  This way we can log the method name in our access logs.

I know there is a `RpcRequestBuilder`  class, but I dont know how I would extend it to add the  method name to the header or URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link could help you.. http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2009/12/22/custom-http-headers-with-gwt-rpc/

EDIT : 
you should set methodName before invoking remote service method..

```
public class MyRpcRequestBuilder extends RpcRequestBuilder() {
    String methodName;
     public void setMethodName(String name) {
         methodName = name;
     }
     @Override  
    protected RequestBuilder doFinish(RequestBuilder rb) {    
        RequestBuilder rb = super.doFinish(rb);    
        rb.setHeader("method", methodName);    
        return rb;  
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I really want to know is how do I get the method name to put into the header?

Comment: well, there are not any generic solution to your problem. But you can do it by overriding doFinish method RpcRequestBuilder class..

Comment: My teammate ended up using this but overwrote the doSetRequestData() method.  He parsed out the rpcMethodName and set it in the header.  He searched for Rpc|rpceMethodName| and extracted teh rpcMethodName.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should solve this problem different, if possible. Here is another thought.

The method name is actually already sent, but buried as you said. But on the server side you can catch this name. In the `RemoteServiceServlet` there is a protected method `onAfterRequestDeserialized` which gives you a decoded version of the data and is specific for these kind of things. It contains the method name. Simply extend this method and log the method name there. This way you don't have to add tricks to your client side code.

Comment: Once you get the method name you need to do something server-specific to log it. If for example you are using JBoss or Tomcat you can put the method name in to the request:

request.setAttribute("GWT_METHOD_NAME", methodName);


and then log it using AccessLogValve and the pattern: %{GWT_METHOD_NAME}r